# 'float' object is not callable хотя я пробовал удалять скобки и/или менять тип с помощу int()

Tags: python

```
import turtle
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
import objects

win_w = GetSystemMetrics(0)
win_h = GetSystemMetrics(1)

window = turtle.Screen()
x1 = -(win_w / 2) + (0.065 * win_w)
x2 = (win_w / 2) - (0.065 * win_w)
window.bgcolor("black")
window.setup(win_w, win_h)
window.tracer()

player_1 = objects.Game_element([x1, 0], 5, 1)

player_2 = objects.Game_element([x2, 0], 5, 1)

ball = objects.Game_element([0, 0], 1, 1)

window.listen()


def up_1():
    player_1.sety(player_1.ycor() + 10)


window.onkeypress(up_1, "w")

while True:
    window.update()
```

Файл Objects.py:

```
 import turtle


class Game_element():
    def __init__(self, goto,x,y):
        self = turtle.Turtle()
        self.color("white")
        self.shape("square")
        self.penup()

        self.shapesize(x,y)
        self.goto(goto)

    def ycor(self):
        self._ycor = turtle.ycor()
        return self._ycor

    def sety(self,y):
        self._sety = turtle.sety(y)
        return self._sety
```

Comment: при нажатии кнопки w на кординатах  0,0 создаёться черныйй указатель не понимаю почему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы зря сделали одинаковое название и у метода и у поля класса. Упрощу ситуацию для понятности:

```
class Game_element():

    def ycor(self):
        self.ycor = 3.14 # <-- ПРОБЛЕМА ТУТ
        return self.ycor

player1 = Game_element()
y = player1.ycor() # первый вызов будет успешным
y = player1.ycor() # а второй вызов уже не получится
```

Выходит ошибка на втором вызове:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-3595c07fa764> in <module>()
      7 player1 = Game_element()
      8 y = player1.ycor()
----> 9 y = player1.ycor()

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

После выполнения строки `self.ycor = turtle.ycor()` переменная `ycor` экземпляра класса `player1` больше не указывает на метод `def ycor()`, она указывает на значение, полученное через вызов `turtle.ycor()`, а там видимо число с плавающей точкой. Поэтому такая ошибка.

Назовите метод класса как-то по-другому, не также, как называется поле. Для того, чтобы не было такой путаницы, часто принимают такую конвенцию - называть поля класса с подчёркиванием перед именем. Тогда вы их точно не перепутаете с методами. Например, так:

```
def ycor(self):
    self._ycor = turtle.ycor()
    return self._ycor
```

Comment: я так сделал тоесть поменял название методов из sety на _sety но ошибки любые вообще пропали но объект так и не меняет координаты

Comment: @RuslanUriadko Добавьте в вопрос **ПОЛНЫЙ** текст ошибки, с указанием строки, в которой она происходит. И обновите код в вопросе, если вы его поменяли, а ошибка остаётся.

Comment: код обновил, ошибки в консоли нет, попросту исчезла, но к сожалению объект все равно не меняет свои кординаты.